# How to self join mysql table on id

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table named Products which looks like so:

```
prd_id    prd_name    prd_ref_id      prd_status
----------------------------------------------------
1         Prod A      0               Available
2         Prod X      3               Out of Stock
3         Prod G      1               Available
```

As you can see the `prd_ref_id` refers to the same table, but different id. If there is no reference it will be `0`.

I want to write a query such that, say I have `prd_id as 2` then the query should return:

```
prd_id    prd_name    prd_ref_name     prd_status
2         Prod A      Prod 3           Out of Stock
```

I think I need to somehow use self join, but it keeps giving me syntax errors.

```
select p.*,p2.prd_name    
from products p    
self join products p2
on p2.prd_id = p.prd_ref_id
```

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: Just remove the `self`. There is no `self` keyword, just a `join` or `inner join`.

Comment: However, you should probably use `NULL` instead of `0` for those without a reference, because it would allow you more easily to use `LEFT JOIN` without adding logic to handle the `0` case.

Answer (score 2):

It is called a *self join* in speech, because you are joining a table to itself. But in syntax there is no difference to joining on another table, so you can just `inner` or `left` join as usual. Of course you need aliases to distinguish between the two, but you already did that correctly.

```
select p.*,p2.prd_name    
from products p
left join products p2 on p2.prd_id = p.prd_ref_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the word `self`. It is not a keyword in sql.

```
select p.*,p2.prd_name from products p join products p2 on p2.prd_id = p.prd_ref_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Self join syntax is like below:

```
select p.*,p2.prd_name    
from products p   
join products p2
where p2.prd_id = p.prd_ref_id
```

Comment: It's simple for beginners.

Comment: 'Normal' joins are simple too and much clearer to understand, especially if you need an outer join situation. Besides, OP is already using the join keyword.

Answer (score 0):

These are three kinds of join in the sql:

- INNER JOIN:Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH
  tables
- LEFT JOIN:Return all rows from the left table, and the matched
  rows from the right table
- RIGHT JOIN:Return all rows from the right
  table, and the matched rows from the left table

so,i think that the you should make the table p as the left table,and left join p2.

```
SELECT p.*,p2.prd_name FROM products p LEFT JOIN products p2 ON p2.prd_id = p.prd_ref_id
```